# Copy members from one Distribution Group to another Distribution Group in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2007

**I am trying to copy members from one Distribution group to another Distribution but the members are distribution groups not users\mailbox RecipientType: MailUniversalDistributionGroup

> `Get-DistributionGroupMember "A" | Get-mailbox |
>   Add-DistributionGroupMember “b”`

**This doesn't work because members of DL A are Distribution group (nested DLs )  not users**  **another way I tried **

> `$bankmanager = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "A" | select
>   DistinguishedName add-distributiongroupmember -Identity "B" -Member
>   $bankmanager`

error

```
getting Add-DistributionGroupMember : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 
'Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientIdParameter' required by parameter 'Member'. Specified method is not supported.**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to do what you need:

```
Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "A" | % {add-distributiongroupmember -Identity "B" -Member $_.Name}
```

The Add-DistributionGroupMember cmdlet doesn't look like it accepts pipeline inputs like you would normally expect. To get around this I used `%` which is the pipeline alias for `foreach` so for each object in the results call add to group. The $_ represents the current object in the for each loop.